# Json mixed alphanumeric key sort order

Tags: json, google-chrome, sorting

I use json to store the results of online selection and input. I have a special procedure to stringify json objects (for filtering, arrays displayed in single line etc). I have given all collection elements names - e.g. "Tracks" - with their linked elements given number labels - e.g "231" - to facilitate generation of infinite unique links. When written to file this makes it easy especially during development to check collections at the bottom and latest additions directly above them.

Chrome automatically achieves this, whereas other browsers do not (IE not tested).

As I am having trouble with animation and the latest Chrome update I would like to achieve what Chrome does to the string so I can get the same convenience with Firefox. Does anyone know how?

Comment: Sorry found a place in procedure to sort elements before stringify; just posting helped find solution!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I inserted in case it is helpful

```
//set alphanumeric order
        strArr = [];
        numArr = [];
        for(n in nset){
            if(parseInt(n)){
                numArr.push([parseInt(n),nset[n]]);
            }
            else{
                strArr.push([n,nset[n]]);
            }
        }
        numArr.sort(function(a,b){return a-b});
        nset = {};
        arr = numArr.concat(strArr);
        for(a=0; a<arr.length; a+=1){
            nset[arr[a][0].toString()] = arr[a][1];
        }
```